# force IE9 not to use the latest rendering engine?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, cross-browser

I'm stuck in IE9 of my program. When I load my page, IE9 doesn't show up anything, after I turn on the compatibility view, the initial page was able to show up. I've tried hard to find what's in my program that made IE9 fail to display the content, but cannot find any good references. I would only guess that it might be the css code that has caused the errors.

My question is: Can I explicitly force IE9 not to use the latest rendering engine? If not, how can I change my css or html file in order to get it work under standard mode?

Btw, I'm using html5, and I pasted some snippet of css code from my program, hope someone can help me with that. Thanks.

```
.tokenPanel {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #aa0404;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.TokenPanelWelcomeLabel {
    font-family: sans-serif serif;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

.gwt-MenuBar .gwt-MenuItem {
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    border: 1px #aa0404 solid;
    background-color: #ffffe0;
}

.gwt-PopupPanelGlass {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: literal("alpha(opacity=30)");
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: IE9 by default follows the same rules as the other browsers.  Have you verified this problem exists in those browsers?  The only way to solve this is a process of elinmination.  Modify the css code one by one until you figure out what is non-standard.  You wanting to use compatability mode is just bad programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, you have to explicitly set compatibility mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

More about this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325.aspx#SetMode

**EDIT** Of course CSS3 and HTML5 might not be supported with an emulation of a previous IE version.

Comment: That or press f12 and select the standard from the web developer tool

Comment: Awesome!! Hope this can help ppl who has the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If sinsedrix's anwser didn't work when you deployed your site in IIS7, try put this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Seems this settings in system.webServer in your machine config will overwrite the meta data in the html header.